# How can I create a simple time-based notification for Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass

I'm basically working on an alarm app, where at certain times (e.g. 7pm, 10:30am), Glass should alert the user. I think this will work by creating a live card, but I don't know how to create one at a certain time and I can't find anything online about dealing with this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the [Timer GDK sample project](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-timer-sample) on the Google Glass GitHub repository.

To give it more alarm functionality, you can use the Calendar class (java.util.Calendar).